# Eclipse is treating package names oddly

Tags: eclipse, package

My original problem occurred whenever I would try to export a .jar file. Eclipse would say there was a missing build path for two of the classes. I decided that deleting the package that files were in would be a decent idea but now every time I try to recreate the package it acts weird. I will tell it to make the package "com.gmail.developnickmaster21.FancyClan" and instead it will make a package with the name of "com.gmail.developnickmaster21" and a folder inside of it with the name of "FancyClan". How can I fix this?

[image: How Eclipse makes the package]

FYI: I have two copies of an external jar file because my flash-drive that contains the workspace appears as a different drive on my home and school computers.